# How to differentiate Tumeric from Lesser Galangal without digging it up?

Tags: identification

I planted tumeric and lesser galangal in the same garden plot.  I have a bunch of very similar-looking plants.  Is there a reasonably easy way to tell them apart?

I *suspect* I have only one lesser galangal plant up, and I think it is this because the leaves are a bit bigger, but I am not at all sure.  The leaves, apart from size, look identical and the plant I think that is lesser galangal has leaves that look more or less identical to commercially available tumeric leaves (but the tumeric plants I have are a bit smaller).  Since this is narrowed down to two possibilities based on what was planted, I don't believe that images would help, so much as textual descriptions separating the two plants.

Comment: Yeah I have only seen them in pictures, but I think the gangal does have broader leaves... At least you didn't plant ginger too, right?

Comment: I have ginger there too, but the plants look very different from Tumeric and Lesser Galangal.  Leaves are narrower and the plant is far more upright.  the arrangement of leaves is different too.

Comment: Well I guess it depends on which ginger, as they are all 3 gingers.

Comment: By ginger here I mean culinary ginger.  Yes they are all in the same family.  But culinary ginger is about as distinct from the others as a gallical rose plant is from a hybrid tea rose (meaning to say similar leaves but otherwise very little resemblance).

Comment: More than same family, at least tumeric and gangal are in the same genus. I am not sure what the binomial for what I call ginger is.

Comment: Zingiber officinale for ginger, Alpina galanga for lesser galangal, and Curcuma longa for tumeric, so all different genuses as far as I can tell.

Comment: How about smell, how do the leaves smell if you crush them?

Comment: I suspect they are close enough I could use them interchangeably for cooking.

Comment: You are right on the taxonomy, for some reason I thought tumeric was in alpina, along with a bunch of other things with ginger in their common name... Well I guess I don't have any experience with lesser gangal, I some with greater gangal from thai cooking, and tumeric from Indian cooking (purchased from the south East Asian store though.) I did get tumeric to sort of grow, but the Great Basin isn't really the place for it. Well I guess good luck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually did some more research and found that I didn't have any galangal growing yet at all.  No idea why it doesn't like that area.  I was also able to locate galangal in neighbor's gardens for visual comparison.

It turns out that galangal is more similar to ginger than tumeric in its growing pattern.  Tumeric has a bunch of leaves coming from a short stock, while galangal has a tall stock with alternating leaves.  The leaves are much more broad but tougher and less obviously veined than ginger.